# Drop Down Filter in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, drop-down-menu, vlookup

Im  having an issue with the drop down filter in excel. Currently as it stands I have an excel sheet with a few columns that won't be changed add order columns that are sorted by date.

I am currently wondering the best way to fill to the date columns in the excel sheet.

Currently I've worked on doing a drop down to select the period of what I want to figure out as well as a table which currently says the dates in this month.

The first picture is what I currently have at the moment at the second picture is what I hope to achieve which is that when I select the period of this month which is on the top of the page it then only selects the current month of work.

I've tried numerous formulas for this and I'm currently getting errors and sometimes just blank.

I'm not used to excel so if anyone has an idea of what formulas I could use I was currently following a YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hj6JSSQIrdw&t=1204s)
[[[Currently what I have at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVVEW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgq3r.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTneh.png)

[What I hope to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKieA.png)

I tried different formulas and I hope that under the date column when i select this month in the select period drop down then i can have it filtered to the current date.

Ive tried putting the dates in a different sheet but that's not working either

Comment: I think I've figured out what you're asking for. So you input the state date and end date, and you want a sum or count (?) of the projects by the dimensions Big Project/Medium project between those dates. You will want to use a `SUMIFS` or `COUNTIFS`, but we can't write the formulas not knowing where the data comes from.

Comment: Hi Mark, so the start date and the end date are for the table above it to get which period it like like say this month or quarter one. What I hope to do is that when i have project name and number and instead of say twelve columns which are marked January to december i have just date and when i select in the 'select period' drop down say 'this month' the column date only shows me marchs data.

Comment: You need to edit your post to better explain what your inputs and expected outputs are. What you're asking is relatively simple and I would still recommend a sumifs or countifs (since we're still not sure what data you're pulling or from where). You can use the table to populate the start and end dates based on your drop-down selection, and do the sumifs/countifs against those lookups, using the lookups as the upper and lower bounds of your sumifs.

Comment: Hi Mark, ah ok thank you, ill have an edit now. yeah the data being pulled in are all on the excel sheet, its manually updated. yes the table is populated the start and end dates but the issue is getting the revelent data into the table like if I only want one month filtered and also the dates currently are as headers which is where im having a road block

Comment: with a sumifs you can say `=sumifs( [sum range], [date column], ">=" & [start date],  [date column], "=<" & [Enddate])` so you're able to filter out the data outside of your date range. the text in [ ] is meant to show the ranges or data you'd plug in. Though i'm not quite understanding what you mean that dates are headers, but this is why you need to explain your situation specifically. What inputs look like, and what expected outputs are, and what you've tried. Otherwise it's just theory on how to approach it.

Comment: Hi Mark, great let me try that, apologies, in the first picture in the above question i have project name, project id, jan 24, feb 24.... and ideally i would like just one column as date and once its filtered at the top then it can then filter into the excel table

Comment: I see, so the ask seems quite different from what I was thinking, you're not summing by dimensions, you want a formula to produce a list of the projects, their numbers, and the dates between those dates. Still doable, but quite different. You have 365? You will likely be looking at a Spill formula to produce a `unique` list of the projects, but pulling in the additional data as well.

Comment: Some formulas that will be helpful for this are `UNIQUE`, `FILTER`, `CHOOSECOLS`/`CHOOSEROWS`, `SEQUENCE`, `SORT`. These are spill formulas you can nest around each other to filter out data outside of your date ranges or columns you don't want displayed, re-order and you can do other formulas to this spill range.

Comment: @ali97 are you trying to use a formula to write values to a cell? That is, run a formula (or click a line in drop-down) in `A1`, and get `5` or `abc` written to `A2`, permanently?

Comment: Hi all, so Ive tried a filter formula and it's not working unfortunately. I'm trying to get a formula that when I select a certain time frame then it will populate the table with the certain dates, I think what is throwing me off is the dates from January to December as columns as shown in picture one but ideally when I have the table set as this month then the date column populates only March and likewise if it's quarter one or two. So I want the project table to be populated based on the month I choose

Comment: I'm now thinking about maybe a vlookup might help, like as in if I have all the dates I'm a seperate sheet like the month as columns and the information under it and then a vlookup from the first sheet under date. I've tried it but it's coming up an error but would I be on the right track